# Switch between single line and multi-line CSS with Espresso

Tags: css, macrabbit-espresso

I have a long single-line CSS file that I would like to convert using Espresso to block style. Is there an automatic way to do this with Espresso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in way to do that in Espresso 2. But there's the [Barista-Beautifier.sugar](https://github.com/jancbeck/Barista-Beautifier.sugar) which also reformats CSS into nicely readable code.